# Meaning of "日にち会うかな？"

Tags: meaning, slang

What does 日にち会うかな？ means in the excerpts below?

[1](http://blog.livedoor.jp/tuckeym/archives/52937510.html):

> 太巻きのお題は来年にしようかな？
>   **日にち会うかな？**
>   まぁ今年は、太巻きは買ってきて、豚汁作って食べますか。

[2](https://twitter.com/28_uryu11/status/626261144458498048):

> A: テニスやろ
>   B: みんな**日にち会うかな？**(^^;)笑

[3](http://off3.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/offevent/1117465985/):

> それ見たいんだけど**日にち会うかな**…_|￣|○

[4](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LhsvFwEGHacJ:twtrp.jp/user/TmyGackt%20&cd=17&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu):

> 2日に帰る予定だから、**日にち会うかな？**

Despite my efforts I have failed to grasp a meaning that would fit all cases. My guesses so far:

- Maybe 会う should actually be 合う?
- 3 seems to imply "Sorry I can't go", while 4 sounds optimistic.

Comment: Are you assuming 会う by transcribing examples you've heard, or did you actually see them written this way?  Before I even read the question, I thought it more likely to be 合う.

Comment: @istrasci: It is not something that I heard, it is written, I just copy/pasted.

Comment: Maybe 会う should actually be 合う? >> そう思います。「合う」であるべきなんですが、うっかり変換を間違ってもみんなあんまり気にしないみたいで。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just typo for 日にちが合う (=schedules meet). This is the casual version of 日程が合う or 都合が合う. (In English *meet* (=会う) is used here, but that's probably a coincidence)